# Expressing logarithms in terms of $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given that $\log_{10}{5}=a$ and $\log_{3}{10}=b$, express $\log_{48}{65}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

I tried various transformations of $\log_{48}{65}$ and got:

$$\log_{48}{65} =\frac{\log_{10}{65}}{\log_{10}{48}}=\frac{a+\log_{10}{13}}{\frac{1}{b}+4\log_{10}2}=\frac{a+\log_{10}{13}}{\frac{1}{b}+4-4a}$$

I'm stuck here since I'm really not sure what to do with $\log_{10}{13}$. Have I approached this problem in a wrong way, and if so, what is a better way to approach it?

Comment: we have $a^10 = 5$ and $b^3 =10.$ your problem says $x^48 = 65$. So you could say $x^(4.8b^3)=6.5b^3 \implies x = (6.5b^3)^{\frac{1}{4.8b^3}}$. Though this is probably not what they want. My point is that the question is vague.

Comment: $\log_{10}13$ is an acceptable constant.  It's not particularly clear that you aren't finished.

Comment: I agree that the problem is a bit vague. Let's say that logarithms that are irrational aren't acceptable constants for the sake of the problem not being trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just put all in terms of $\log_{10} = \log$ (just for familiarity with days of yore):

$\begin{align*}
  \log 5
    &= a \\
  \log 2
    &= \log 10 - \log 5 \\
    &= 1 - a \\
  \log_3 10
    &= \frac{\log 10}{\log 3} \\
    &= \frac{1}{\log 3} \\
    &= b \\
  \log_{48} 65
    &= \frac{\log 65}{\log 48} \\
    &= \frac{\log 5 + \log 13}{\log 3 + \log 16} \\
    &= \frac{(a + \log 13)}{1/b + \log 16} \\
    &= \frac{b (a + \log 13)}{1 + 4 b \log 2} \\ 
    &= \frac{b (a + \log 13)}{1 + 4 b (1 - a)}
 \end{align*}$

Can't get rid of the 13, as a prime it can't be written as a product of powers of 10 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around, I noticed a few things:

$log_{3}5=ab$

$log_{3}2=a-ab$

Maybe use these facts after converting $log_{48}65$ in base $3$?

Comment: All I got was $\frac{ab+\log_{3}{13}}{1+4a-4ab}$, and again I'm not sure what to do after that.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the second equation is incorrect. It should be $log_{3}2=b-ab$